# Bootloader is not working with hex file of size 278kb?

Tags: linker, bootloader, pic32

I have created the USB_DEVICE bootloader for my project. In that I am triggering bootloader when there is data written on valid flash address 0x9D061000. In my application firmware, I am initialising flash, and then writing data on the address 0x9D061000 to go in firmware upgraded mode. My linker scripts are attached below. My firmware size is ~278kB. My other firmware with same linker but size <100KB is working fine with the bootloader. Is it the hex file size error? or did I restricted addresses in linker file. I don't know how to edit the linker file, And I don't got any reference or guide for editing it.

Note: I copy pasted my .ld linker files to txt files.

[application_linker_file.txt](http://www.microchip.com/forums/download.axd?file=0;949865)

[bootloader_linker_file.txt](http://www.microchip.com/forums/download.axd?file=1;949865)

*I am using PIC32MX795F512L, MPLABx3.40, Harmony version 1.7.1 ans XC32 compiler version 1.42*

Comment: I tried disabling the system interrupt on powering on of application firmware. Still its not working.

Comment: And also if I disabled few modules, and reduced code size to around 250Kb, its working.